# How to obtain rootProject.name and make it available to app, testing and distribution?

Tags: gradle, properties, project

In build.gradle it is simple enough:

```
println "project name $name"
```

... but that wouldn't be available with a distributed version of the app. Nor do I understand how I can easily access that value from inside testing and app code.

The name should be available in "settings.gradle": hopefully this should contain a line like:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyProject'
```

If I want to incorporate this name into a test, and also into app code, and also to make sure that that info is available to a distributed version of the app, using `installDist` for example, it seems to me that the best way might be to automate, prior to testing, building and distributing, a task which extracts that information from settings.gradle and puts it into a .properties file under src/main/resources.

How would I do that? Or... is there a better approach?

PS a possible use case might be for configuring the path of a logfile: .../logging/MyProject... There are probably others.

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle:

```
task copySettingsGradle {
    doFirst {
        ant.copy(file: 'settings.gradle',
                todir: 'src/main/resources',
                overwrite: true,
                failonerror: true)
    }
}
classes.dependsOn copySettingsGradle
```

app code:

```
        URL settingsGradleURL = App.class.getResource( '/settings.gradle' )
        ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse( settingsGradleURL )
        def projectName = conf.rootProject.name
```

... the point about this being that it works both during Gradle development and in the distributed app...